# Issue in Mapping cassandra tables with hive tables

Tags: cassandra, hive, hadoop2

I am tyring to map Cassandra table as an external table for hive using Cassandra Storage Handler to read cassandra's records from hive.

**Version Details:**

Cassandra 2.1.8
Hive 1.2.1
Hadoop 2.6.0

**Example Query**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS records (id string, name string, pages int) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("cassandra.columns.mapping" = "id,name,pages", "cassandra.cf.name" = "records", "cassandra.host" = "192.168.0.233" , "cassandra.port" = "9160", "cassandra.partitioner" = "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner","cassandra.ks.name" = "hivecassandra");
```

**Getting the following error**

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.initSerdeParams(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/lazy/LazySimpleSerDe$SerDeParameters;
```

Comment: Have you tried using the query structure as shown for [CQL3](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/hive-support-for-cassandra-cql3/) (eg: using `org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlStorageHandler` and its properties instead of `org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.CassandraStorageHandler`)?

Comment: I have tried that too with the following query.  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hivecassandra.messages(message_id string, author string, body string) STORED By 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("cql.primarykey" = "message_id, author", "comment"="check", "read_repair_chance" = "0.2", "dclocal_read_repair_chance" = "0.14", "cassandra.host" = "192.168.0.233" , "cassandra.port" = "9160", "gc_grace_seconds" = "989898", "bloom_filter_fp_chance" = "0.2", "compaction" = "{'class' : 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'}", "replicate_on_write" = "false", "caching" = "all")

Comment: Getting same error as mentioned above. If i use hive 0.9.0 this query works and mapping as external table. Im getting this issue with hive 1.2.1.